# как мне расширить javascript функцию?

Tags: javascript

как мне расширить функцию при этом не изменив старый код

```
function export_excel() {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location,
        method: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        headers: {
            excelize: 'True'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'Отчет.xlsx';
            document.body.append(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    });
}
```

я хочу чтоб function export_excel(text) принимал text, и передавал a.download = text;, но мне надо чтоб старые вызовы этой функции работали коректно

Comment: Передавайте аргумент в функцию, а когда вызываете её - передавайте параметр. Аргумент служит как переменная, по этому в коде её нужно где-то использовать. А параметр - это данные которые прилетают в переменную. Что значит старые вызовы непонятно.

Comment: @WalkMess я это понимаю, если я щас добавлю аргументы к функции и укажу a.downald этот, другие страницы который использовали этот скрипт без аргументов не будут работать. Например если ```function export_excel(text){ a.downald = text; } ``` я так сделаю, тогда старые вызовы которые вызовали без аргумента text ошибку выдают

Comment: Вам стоило это уточнить в вопросе. Функции можно делать аргумент по умолчанию, таким образом, если ничего при вызове не задано, туда попадёт дефолтное значение. Ниже есть пример!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте дефолтное значения для аргумента:

```js
function export_excel(name = 'Отчет.xlsx') {
  console.log(name);
}

export_excel(); // Выведет Отчет.xlsx
export_excel('text'); // Выведет text
```

Comment: мне надо a.downald надо чтоб сами могли прописать, какое имя будет у файла

Comment: Пропишите любой дефолт и проверьте, если это дефолт, тогда передайте значения, которые внутри функции, иначе дефолту присвойте данные при вызове функции.